# WYSIWIG Markdown Editor for any TextArea as Chrome or Firefox Extension

Tags: markdown, editor, documentation

Our Non developer team struggles to document over Git pages (We are using Gitlab) and over Youtrack (agile tracking tool, similar to JIRA).

Is there an extension for Chrome or Firefox where it automatically gives WYSIWIG Markdown Editor on top of any Text area. Where they can format using WYSIWIG Editor and in background it saves Markdown format inside TextArea.

I am yet to get that type of extension. I've got following two links but need marriage of these two.
[WYSIWIG Markdown editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16796452/markdown-wysiwyg-editor-and-preview-in-same-textarea) and [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pjhancoeamcahkmbmgoonbaggjbpijoc)

Answer (score 0):

How about the [GitHub Writer](https://ckeditor.com/github-writer/) Chrome extension from the CKEditor team?